# the code crashes due to an issue on connect'ing signal & slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have the below code that creates `people` objects and stores the objects via `QVector`. For debugging purposes, I added a signal called `foo()` and a Slot called `outputData()` to see if QVector (`list`) stores the values correctly.

I connected the signal and slot via:

```
 connect(People, SIGNAL(foo()), this , SLOT( outputData() ) );
```

on mainwindow.cpp file. Gcc builds the code and does not output any error neither warning. However, when I run the program, `SIGSEV` kills the process.

Could anyone tell me what is the mistake on the `connect()`?

And is it the correct usage of `QVector` to store objects?

**code.pro**

```
QT       += core gui
QT += network

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = untitled1
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp \
    people.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h \
    people.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

**mainwindow.h**

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QUdpSocket>
#include <QString>
#include "people.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);

    ~MainWindow();
   // void outputData();
public slots:
    void outputData();
private slots:
    void readyRead();



signals: void foo();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QUdpSocket udpSocket;
    people *People;
    void processPendingDatagrams();
    void udp_transfer(QString data);
    void ParseData(QByteArray data);
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

---

**people.h**

```
#ifndef PEOPLE_H
#define PEOPLE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QString>
#include <QMainWindow>

class people : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    people();
    people(QString Name, int Age);
    QString getName();
    int getAge();
    void setName(QString Name);
    void setAge(int Age);


private:
   QString name;
   int age;
};

#endif // PEOPLE_H
```

---

**main.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

---

**mainwindow.cpp**

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QHostAddress>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QVector>


QVector<people*> list;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
   udpSocket.bind(2222); 
    connect(&udpSocket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()));
    connect(People, SIGNAL(foo()), this , SLOT( outputData() ) );   //HERE IS THE PROBLEMATIC PART!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
}


MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}


void MainWindow::readyRead(){
    do {
      QByteArray datagram;
      datagram.append(udpSocket.pendingDatagramSize());
      udpSocket.readDatagram(datagram.data(), datagram.size());
      ParseData(datagram);
    } while (udpSocket.hasPendingDatagrams());

}



void MainWindow::ParseData(QByteArray data){
    QString name;
    int i = 0;
    for (i=0; i<4; i++){
        name.append(QString("%1").arg(data[i]));
    }

    QString temp;
    for (i=0; i<2; i++){
        temp.append(QString("%1").arg(data[i+4]));
    }
    int age = temp.toInt();
    People = new people(name, age);
    qDebug() << "msg is received";
    list.push_back(People);
    emit foo();

}


void MainWindow::outputData(){
    qDebug() << "size:" << list.size();
    qDebug() <<  "name:" << list[0]->getName();
    qDebug() <<  "Age:" << list[0]->getAge();
}
```

---

**people.cpp**

```
#include "people.h"

people::people(){
   name = "No name";
   age = 0;
}

people::people(QString Name, int Age){
   name = Name;
   age = Age;
}

QString people::getName(){
    return name;
}

int people::getAge(){
   return age;
}

void people::setName(QString Name){
    name = Name;
}

void people::setAge(int Age){
    age = Age;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`People` seems to be an uninitialized pointer. You don't create a `people` object, but just use the uninitialized pointer in the `connect` call. This will then try to access a `people` object at whatever random memory location `People` might point to, causing a segmentation fault.

You probably wanted to create the `People` object first, for example by adding `People(new people())` to the initializer list.

Comment: thank you, it solves the problem. if you have time, could you also tell me whether the qvector usage correct to store objects (People)?

Comment: Looking at it again, `foo()` is a signal of `MainWindow`, not `people`, so wouldn't it really be `connect(this, SIGNAL(foo()), ...)`? And `People` then wouldn't really need to be a member variable of the class, since it's only used in `ParseData()`. It could just be a local variable in that function. About the vector: Pushing to it and accessing the elements like that should work. Maybe it would be more appropriate to make it a member variable of `MainWindow` instead of a global variable, but that depends on what else you are planning to do with it.

Comment: thanks a lot. I had noticed the problems (with signal) that I was trying to solve it. It is also solved after your comment:)